# 4k vs 5k Monitor as "Retina" on older MacPro

Tags: display, mac-pro

I am currently running my MacPro (late 2010) with a 30" (2840 pix wide) and often an old iMac 27 as a secondary display.

I'd really like to upgrade to something more crisp - the difference on my MBP Retina is huge.

I thought about getting an Eizo 32" 4k - but it will obviously not be as crisp as the 5k models that usually come around as 27".

Does someone have experiences in these scenarios? It's virtually impossible to find that in the store to test before ordering.

Main application is software development, so usually heavy on text editing, with some graphics works in between. Real space is always rare, but I tend to like a bit bigger fonts lately...

(Graphics card is an eVGA GF GTX 680, main memory is maxed out)

Comment: voted to close as opinion-based. tbh, it's way too vague - you want higher-res, but you need the text bigger... seems counter-productive. prescription spectacles would be cheaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this question - here's what I made out of it. Given that the graphics card might get to its limits with 4k anyway, I chose to give the Eizo 3237 a try with the 4k resolution at 140 DPI. Running on native resolution is small but crisp, as expected.

Using HiDPI modes and scaling up works really nice as long as you don't hit your nose onto the screen.

Quality-wise this thing is an instant buy - although I might be biased as Eizo monitors have never failed to make me happy in the past (had a couple of good other ones as well - though I'd rank them a bit below in terms of perceived quality).